# How to send message from background script to extension thread/process

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Ok so I have this in my manifest.json file:

```
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
```

in my background.js script I have this:

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
  port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {

    // now, I want to forward `msg` to the extension process itself

  });
});
```

as indicated, I would like to send the message from the background script to my extension.

Is the right way to do this, using:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#connect

So I suppose I do this in background.js:

```
var port = chrome.runtime.connect('my-extension-id');
port.postMessage('foo');
```

I would have guessed that my background script would already have some sort of default connection/channel to the extension, do I have to manually set that up? I would guess that I would only have to manually set that up if I wanted to communicate across different extensions.

**update:**
I have this in `background.js` now

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log('background.js received a message');
  sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
  sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
  sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
  sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
});
```

it looks like sendResponse can only be called once. I need to open a "persistent" connection between background.js and the popup, so that I can transmit multiple messages over time.

Comment: `send the message from the background script to my extension` - the background script is also your extension. Do you want to send a message to the popup? Usually it's the other way around because popup exists only when shown. Or a content script? Usually it's the other way around because content scripts run only when a matching page loads. Anyway, you don't need to specify the extension id when messaging within your own extension.

Comment: @wOxxOm yeah I mean send a message from the background script to the popup

Comment: I assume that the popup is intended to be the main application window for your extension?

Comment: I need to send a message both ways - from the popup to background.js and vice versa

Comment: The popup doesn't have to be the main part. Port messaging is used only when you need to send lots of messages or in some other special cases. Anyway, usually the popup sends a message via chrome.runtime.sendMessage for a single message and receives a response to that message as shown in the first example in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#simple).

Comment: @wOxxOm sorry..I am not following..I am not seeing an example where the popup initiates a message, and the background.js script responds

Comment: 1. The popup sends a message https://puu.sh/yRWE6/8fe0b6bb02.png 2. The background script responds https://puu.sh/yRWEz/9dde483ff9.png

Comment: I think that's from a content script, not a background script, right? there's a big difference I think

Comment: No, there's no difference.

Comment: a content script can talk with a random tab, but a background script can't, the background script seems to be more tied into your extension than the content script, but I am still trying to figure this out..

Comment: There's no difference when the popup or the content script sends a message - the background script simply responds to that message using `sendResponse` as shown in the documentation. Start with the simple implementation, no need to overcomplicate right off the bat.

Comment: but with regard to the popup being the main window - if you were to choose something other than the popup being the main window, wouldn't you either have to open a new tab or use a native application window?

Comment: It obviously depends on what your extension does.

Comment: My extension doesn't need to do anything but talk with the browser, my extension just needs to listen for DOM events from a particular tab. It displays a list of DOM events for the user in a useful way, with the UI.

Comment: `a content script can talk with a random tab` - each page receives its own instance of your content script, it's not a single one that can talk to "random" tabs, whereas the popup and background page have just one context.

Comment: good to know, I updated the question with more info. basically I need to transmit multiple messages over time (asynchronously) from background.js to the popup

Comment: sendResponse is for single messages only: the initiator (a popup or a content script) sends one message via chrome.runtime.sendMessage, receives one response, the deal is done.

Comment: yes that appears to be the case (although perhaps I can reuse the "sender" object). What I am looking for is a way to transmit multiple messages over time.

Comment: perhaps all it takes is `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` from the background.js script, trying that now

Comment: You can simply send another message from the popup and receive a response. However, in case you want to send a message from the background script without being asked first, the port messaging is the way to go. Also, sometimes the background script isn't needed and you can communicate from your popup to the content script directly, either via port or single messages.

Comment: ok I figured it out, thanks for your help. The big question remaining: the popup is not a good solution for a main window, because if you click on another tab, the popup will disappear...so what is a good solution for a main window?

Comment: I guess you can display it right in the page, so this might be useful: [How to really isolate stylesheets in the Google Chrome extension?](//stackoverflow.com/a/25100953)